# Initialize with calendar with predeifined hours, 7,11,15,19

Tags: c#, time

Initialize with calendar with predefined hours, 7,11,15,19 but i see the values are different when i conver this into datetime

```
        string schduleTimelist = "[7,11,15,19,22]";

        IList<City> cities = new List<City>();
        var sc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(schduleTimelist);
        City city;
        for (int index =1; index < cityCount; index++)
        {
            city = new City();
            city.CityId = index;
            city.Sequence = index;
            SchduleTime schduletime;
            List<SchduleTime> schduletimeList = new List<SchduleTime>();
            foreach (var f in sc)
            {
                schduletime = new SchduleTime();
                DateTimeOffset dt = new DateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Year,DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Month, 
                                                       DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Day, f, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
           }
        }
```

Comment: Which values do you see?

Comment: Which calendar are you using, is it desktop or web app?

Comment: these are static hours of day string schduleTimelist = "[7,11,15,19,22]";